# How to pass a variable to a command line program?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, utility

I want to create files with the current date as prefix and some string as the remaining part of the filename.

Something like this:

```
touch `date +"%Y-%m-%d-"$1`.md hello
```

where `$1` should pick up `hello` and create me a file called `2014-3-3-Hello.md`.

Comment: If you want to use `touch` you need to write your own script (unless it already supports this)

Comment: Depends on how you interprete "possible". If you want touch to do the name generation, you are out of luck. If you just want to create a file with this name, that's easy.

Comment: is that you want to create a file in a script or you need it to run as command from command line?

Comment: i want to create a file with current date in the format i give it but also append a string to the filename before creating it. I want to run a one liner (run as command from command line). Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use command substitution:

```
touch "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-")hello.md"
```

If you want to name a number of files, all ending with `.md`, just wrap the thing in a `for` loop:

```
for baseName in hello world foo bar ; do
    touch "$(date +"%Y-%m-%d-")$baseName.md"
done
```

That will create four files with names like `2014-3-3-hello.md`, `2014-3-3-world.md`, etc.

Answer (score 4):

For convenience, you may want to define a custom function (called `touchdatemd` below) for that:

```sh
$ touchdatemd () { touch $(date +"%Y-%m-%d-")"$1".md; }
```

Test:

```sh
$ mkdir test && cd test
$ touchdatemd hello
$ touchdatemd "I love pie"
$ touchdatemd bye
$ ls
2014-12-28-bye.md   2014-12-28-I love pie.md    2014-12-28-hello.md
```

Comment: Thanks! This is also useful to know.